# HTML - special input email pattern for more options

Tags: html

I need a specific pattern for email input. There should be 2 options:

**john@doe.com**

**john@doe.com:anything**

I need to fit in the ":anything" and make more possibilities after ":".

At the moment I'm using this but it does only validation for normal email:

```
<input class="input-fields" id="formUsername" name="username" type="text" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}" autofocus required/>
```

I tried many combinations but I just can figure out the right one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add ':?\w*' to Your regex, so it would look like

```
[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+.[a-z]{2,3}:?\w*
```

Comment: May i ask how exactly this works? tried to add it here, but did not work

Comment: ':?' means 'zero or one of :'

\w*' means 'zero or more of word character' 

so its e-mail regex with optional ':string'

Comment: well that makes sense, ill try to fit it in to make it work. Thanks for this tip :)

Answer (score 0):

can't you just add more textboxes(only for the extra part [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/9dsoq2do/1/))?

```
Optional(only for blahblahblah):
<input class="optional-fields" title="optional" id="designation" type="text" pattern="[a-z]{5,}">
```

Comment: That does not solve the problem. Imagination of having two email inputs labeled as insert in form of "something@this.com" here and something@this.com:here is kinda unacceptable

Comment: what does `:here` and `:anything` mean

Comment: these are there to identify special users

Comment: like what? example please

Comment: this might be example: john@doe.com:marketing or jane@doe.com:development

Comment: add optional textbox only for the extra part

Comment: That doesnt solve the problem, i need it in exact form. But thanks for effort, gotta make it in js